# Is there any way to build two plots at the same time in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to make two 2x2 plots at the same time. My motivation is because I originally had logic like this:

```
pdf(...)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (subplot_i in c(1,2,3,4)) {
    plot(f(subplot_i))
}
dev.off()
```

but now I want to do something like

```
pdf(..., window=1)
pdf(..., window=2)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (subplot_i in c(1,2,3,4)) {
    plot(f(subplot_i), window=1)
    plot(g(subplot_i), window=2)
}
dev.off(window=1)
dev.off(window=2)
```

that is, build up two plots at the same time.

I could separate it into two loops, but this would double the processing that occurs inside of the loop. I could move all of this processing outside of the loop, but it would come at some considerable effort.

So is what I want possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be possible!

```
f <- function(x) { x }
g <- function(x) { x^2 }
pdf('a.pdf')
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
pdf('b.pdf')
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (subplot_i in c(1,2,3,4)) {
    plot(f(subplot_i))
    dev.set(dev.prev())
    plot(g(subplot_i))
    dev.set(dev.next())
}
dev.off()
dev.off()
```

Comment: One of those files is corrupt on my machine.

Comment: @BondedDust I edited them to have the `.pdf` extension, perhaps that fixes it for you?

Comment: I had already done that.  I didn't think you can have two graphics devices open at the same time, although it is possible to address different items in the "stack" of the interactive device. I just closed all devices and ran it again and do get two plots.